# What should be the structure of the URL to enable indexing of location, time specific events?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, local-seo, geotargeting, json-ld

I have a website that lists movie showtimes, `https://example.com/`.

I want to use JSON-LD to provide information about [`ScreeningEvent`](https://schema.org/ScreeningEvent) (from Schema.org).

I'd like to index events presented on movie specific pages, e.g. `https:/example.com/movies/baby-driver-2017-2257838`. The problem is that the content of the page is geolocation specific, i.e. you are going to see one content if you open the page in London and a different content if you open the page in Birmingham, etc.

- How would I include JSON-LD on this page about the `ScreeningEvent`?
- Do I need to create location specific sub-URLs for the movie?, e.g. `https://example.com/movies/baby-driver-2017-2257838/london-w10`
- Do I need to create date specific sub-URLs for date?, e.g. `https://example.com/movies/baby-driver-2017-2257838/london-w10/2017-06-28`

The question is how to expose this data to Google in a way that would make sense. If `https://example.com/movies/baby-driver-2017-2257838` is going to list all the events for the selected movie, for all of the locations and all of the dates, thats going to be a *very* long JSON-LD feed.

Technically speaking, it would be a valid approach – if Google finds events on the page and manages to correlate the event data (location) with the user data (location) then it could determine the content as relevant/ irrelevant to the user. Once user hits the page he will be displayed the relevant results. Win-win. But, the reality is that Google is not that smart at the moment (it will think I am flooding it with all/ any events) and that's what the user will be given, i.e. low relevance score. Plus, it would make the document size unreasonably large.